# g++ 11.2.0 failed to read compiled module: Bad file data

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++20

I create the precompiled headers for the system headers, one by one

```
$ g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-system-header concepts
$ g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-system-header limits
$ g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-system-header iostream
```

I gathered up the required system headers into Reverse

```
$ cat Reverse
import <concepts>;
import <limits>;
import <iostream>;

$  g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-header Reverse

$ ls gcm.cache/,
Reverse.gcm
```

I try to import the module header

```
$ head Reverse.cpp
import <Reverse>;

$ make
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -I./  -o Reverseexec Reverse.cpp
In module imported at Reverse.cpp:4:1:
./Reverse: error: failed to read compiled module: Bad file data
./Reverse: note: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/,/Reverse.gcm’
./Reverse: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:2: Reverseexec] Error 1
```

I change the imports in Reverse.cpp and it compiles

```
$ head Reverse.cpp
import <concepts>;
import <limits>;
import <iostream>;

$ make
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -o Reverse Reverse.cpp
```

I found what seems to be a related bug.

[Bug c++/98944] [modules] Failed to read compiled module with a non-exported partition.

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /mnt/share/cygpkgs/gcc/gcc.x86_64/src/gcc- 
11.2.0/configure --srcdir=/mnt/share/cygpkgs/gcc/gcc.x86_64/src/gcc-11.2.0 
--prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc -- 
docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C -- 
build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin - 
-without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib -- 
with-gcc-major-version-only --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc -- 
enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap -- 
enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --disable-bootstrap 
--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++,jit --enable-graphite -- 
enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --enable- 
libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada 
--disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog- 
include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without- 
libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default- 
libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.2.0 (GCC)
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Why do I get the error,

```
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -I./  -o Reverseexec Reverse.cpp
In module imported at Reverse.cpp:4:1:
./Reverse: error: failed to read compiled module: Bad file data
./Reverse: note: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/,/Reverse.gcm’
./Reverse: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:2: Reverseexec] Error 1
```

Comment: GCC implementation of modules is still very buggy . There's a meta-bug of problems relating to importing standard headers as header units: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99227. Sadly, modules development for GCC is currently under a hiatus. Please report your bug if it's different from those listed in the metabug.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to more or less work. I'm surprised that I still need to declare everything inline, I thought that constexpr and consteval modifiers would obviate the need for inlining.

To make things more simple, created Makefile,

```
.PHONY: default
default: main ;

gcmcache:
        g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-system-header iostream

hello.o: hello.cpp
        g++ -c -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts hello.cpp

main: main.cpp hello.o
        g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -o main main.cpp hello.o

clean:
        rm hello.o main.exe rm -rf gcm.cache
```

Take it for a run,

```
$ make clean gcmcache main
rm hello.o main.exe rm -rf gcm.cache
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-system-header iostream
g++ -c -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts hello.cpp
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -o main main.cpp hello.o

$ cat hello.cpp
module;

export import <iostream>;

export module hello;

namespace hello {

        export inline constexpr const int TEST = { 1 };

        export inline consteval int foo( const int testing = TEST )
        {
                return testing;
        }
}

$ cat main.cpp
import hello;

int main ( int, char** )
{
        std::cout << hello::TEST << std::endl;
        std::cout << hello::foo( hello::TEST ) << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

All seems to work except for the seemingly redundant inline.

Comment: hello.cpp has a weird structure. It has a global module fragment starting with `module;` despite you aren't `#include`ing anything. Furthermore, I believe that `export import <iostream>;` should be placed after `export module hello;`

Comment: I agree with you. I cleaned it up in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you are trying to gather several standard headers into an importable entity. (I didn't realize of that at first and thought you were facing a bug).

Why not creating a proper module instead of a header-unit?

Here's what I have tried. First, compile the header units as you did:

```
$ g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-system-header concepts
$ g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-system-header limits
$ g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -x c++-system-header iostream
```

Then, create a module exporting all of the headers:

```
export module Reverse;

export import <concepts>;
export import <limits>;
export import <iostream>;
```

and compile it:

```
$ g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -c Reverse.cpp
```

and finaly consume it in a program (Program.cpp):

```
import Reverse;

int main()
{
  static_assert(std::integral<decltype(std::numeric_limits<int>::max())>);
  std::cout << "Hello world\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
$  g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 Program.cpp Reverse.o -o foo
```

it compiles for me and runs correctly.

I tested this using GCC version 11.2 under linux-gnu x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

This works for the special case of bundling up precompiled system header files. What if you need to do something substantive? For example,

```
$ cat Reverse.cpp
export module Reverse;

export import <concepts>;
export import <limits>;
export import <iostream>;

namespace Reverse {
    constexpr int TEST = { 1 };
}

$ cat main.cpp
import Reverse;

int
main(int, char **)
{
    std::cout << Reverse::TEST << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

$ g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 main.cpp Reverse.o -o main
    main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
    main.cpp:6:22: error: ‘Reverse’ has not been declared
    6 |         std::cout << Reverse::TEST << std::endl;
      |                      ^~~~~~~
```

Thank you for you help.

Another concern I have is that the magical way to get experimental modules to work depends strongly on the platform. This will reduce cross-platform compatibility and may require more effort from the build system. I understand that modules are to simplify things yet the disparate methods of using import on VS and g++ may not easily allow cross-platform compatibility. This to me is a shame.

Comment: If you want to make a comment to an answer, please use the “comment” button. If you want to clarify the question, please edit it instead of writing an answer. You cannot use `TEST` because you haven’t `export`ed it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, I needed to export it and inline it. I will probably create a bug for the requirement of inlining with constexpr.

Comment: I'm not sure it is a bug. In the legacy header inclusion model, you also had to `inline` `constexpr` variables if they were ODR-used. I don't know if that requirement has been strengthened for modules irrespectively of whether or not they are ODR-used. Anyway, it's good practice to declare always global `constexpr` variables as `inline constexpr`. In contrast with `static constexpr` member variables, they are not implicitly `inline`.

Comment: Good question, there seems to be some debate. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr, A constexpr specifier used in a function or static data member (since C++17) declaration implies inline. I created a bug in gcc bugzilla "Bug 102545 - [modules] inlining constexpr is required yet it should not be."

Comment: `TEST` is neither a function nor a static data member.

Comment: Good point. My hope is that the use will be consistent whatever constexpr is modifying.